# Simple jQuery script isn't work

Tags: jquery, codepen

I've small problem, `jQuery` isn't working here and I can't see what's wrong, I'm doing. I woud appriciate some help. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
     $("#hcon").show();
  });
});
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/MonkeyCode/pen/YxjOyg)

Comment: Please describe both current and expected behavior.

Comment: replace `visibility: hidden;` with `display: none;` in CSS

Comment: problem solved! Sorry for not mentioning expected behavior it should have presended black box with id of #hcon  when clicked on button. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code doesn't have a function called `myFunction`, check this in the browser dev tools console -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Try this snippet -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
      $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#hcon").show();
        console.log("clicked")
    });
}
```

```css
body {
background-color: lightblue;
}
#container
{
position: relative;
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 50px;
border: 5px solid black;
box-shadow: -20px 30px grey ;
}

#taer {
  
  
}

#button {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
 left: 0; 
right: 0; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
bottom: 20px;
width: 120px; 
background-color: darkgray;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}

#button:hover{
background-color: cyan;
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#hcon {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
height: 300px;
width: 200px;
background-color: black;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<div id="taer">
</div>
  <div id="hcon">
  </div>
 <div id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click!</div>
</div>
```

Also, note that in the css, I changed `visibility: hidden` to `display: none;`.

Comment: Works with como of your advice and advice from srinibas Biswal!! Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Try by making `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`in the css part.

Comment: Works with como of your advice and advice from manish Giri! Tnx!